# how to solve captcha while browsing in a selenium-driven browser with python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and web scraping at all, and now I'm having trouble with captchas.please somebody help me how to captcha handle with python some days I am very tens.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just press the button "solve" in python and it is done.

Usually, websites use different captcha types: simple text captcha, ReCaptcha, Audio, or others.

For example, you can analyze your website and use services that solve captcha for you, in this case:

1. Check if page has a captcha, then send a request to this service to solve.
2. Take the response from captcha solving service and insert it in your page.
3. Submit response and get your content :)

I wouldn't add links to captcha solving services, just search it in google. Usually, these websites have tutorials or plugins for different applications. Also, take a look at automatic solving services(not human-based), they are cheaper and can solve most of the captchas.